# Visual Studio Team System Error Dialog

Tags: tfs

I keep getting the following error, I open visual studio and after a while it just happens. It doesn't seem to affect anything, but it's rather annoying.

Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {B69003B3-C55E-4B48-836C-BC946FC3B28} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80004005.

Any ideas?

Edit: Apparently that error number 80004005 relates to an sql permissions error but I've set my tfs user to have the sysadmin role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's to do with the TFS Power Tools trying to connect to Windows Messenger. It uses Messenger for the Team Members plugin.

I managed to stop the problem by right clicking on the projects Team Members branch (in Team Explorer) and selecting Personal Settings... You may have to wait a bit for the (Working...) to go away and get another error before you can do this.

In the Personal Settings dialogue change the Collaboration Provider to  and Ok.

Restart VS and you shouldn't get the error any more. Of course, if you do want to use the Team Members feature, you might have to find another solution.

Just found the answer on MS Forums - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfspowertools/thread/e80f0333-9ef6-48a0-a409-1a693d5afcc6/?ffpr=0